# Docker перестал видеть файл

Tags: docker

OS: OS X

Пакет приложений: *Docker*, *xhyve*, *docker-machine-driver-xhyve*, *docker-compose*

Есть контейнер с томом:

```
volumes:
- ..:/dir
```

В одном из внутренних каталогов /dir лежит 127 файлов.
Проблема: при получении списка файлов каталога(*функции php*, с помощью *ls*) перестал показываться один файл. При этом если выполнить *mv* то с другим названием всё работает:

```
$ docker-compose run application bash 
$ cat file.php
```

Выводит содержимое файла. Команда *stat* тоже работает. Если делать *ls* - файла нет. При этом если выполнить

```
mv file.php file_.php
```

То в выводе *ls* файл "file_.php" будет. Переименовываем обратно - файла нет.

Из-за чего может такое быть?

Comment: имя этого файла file.php ? или какое то другое?

Comment: "file.php" для примера, на самом деле другое. Самому файлу уже год, только сегодня такая проблема появилась.

Comment: так может вся суть в имени файла?

Comment: а мржет кто то написал алиас на ls